# How do I objectify tabs accordion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to objectify the tabs of a regular accordion.. but it doesn't seem to work. I haven't used this technology, so I'm quite a beginner. Can you please take a look and help me out? Thank you.
Here is the code:

```
<div id="dashboard-learn-knowledge-wrapper">

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" ng-controller="PostsController as learnCtrl">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                <h class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        {{item.title}}
                    </a>
                </h>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in  col-md-8 col-sm-8 " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>{{item.content}}</p>
                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                        <img class="media-object pull-right" ng-src="{{item.photo}}">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
angular.module('DashboardLearn', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('DashboardLearnCtrl', function () {
        var item=this;
        item= [
            {
                'title': 'A',
                'content': "Lorem ipsum ",
                'photo': "http://placekitten.com/g/150/150"
            }
            ];
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A few mistakes,

[Here is a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oliveromahony/jhdq6eej/2/)

Firstly, $scope needs to be passed into the controller so you can the item to it (and the view has access to item).
    Item is an object at the moment (so I swapped it from an array), if you want to leave it as an object it would be something like this:

```
$scope.items= [
        {
            'title': 'A',
            'content': "Lorem ipsum ",
            'photo': "http://placekitten.com/g/150/150"
        }, 
        { 
            'title': 'B',
            'content': "Lorem ipsum B ",
            'photo': "http://placekitten.com/g/151/151"
        }
        ];
```

and you would use an [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) in your html somewhere.

Also the controller was named PostsController instead of DashboardLearnCtrl